# Contract-Popup at Login

Tags: login, scripts, users

I want to give my notebook to guests of my little Hotel as an extra service. I love the Ubuntu guest-account and I think that this is the best possible way to help my guests get free internet-access.

I found out how to "design" their user-accounts with /etc/skel, but unfortunately I have no clue, how to show them a small introduction to the system and a kind of user-agreement "contract" when they login. I read of xmessage, but this is too minimalistic. I'd like to implement some pictures.

Does anyone have any idea of how to make this possible? Would it be possible that the user is logged out automatically if he rejects the user-agreement?

Thank you so much in advance, Steve.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a wild guess, but couldn't you quickly hack up a simple webpage and add an entry to the startup programs that opens a browser displaying that website?

With this initial message being a website you could easily add pictures, even videos and links to internet ressources.

Answer (score 0):

There is `gmessage` which is much nicer looking than `xmessage`, but it won't give you pictures either.

You could have libreoffice open with a document file you have designated for them to see, and you could insert pictures into that. And have a `gmessage` popup asking if they agree to what the document says.

Not a perfect solution, but better than nothing I suppose.